# Using bash for loop variable several times in the same statement

Tags: bash

I ran into a problem I find rather strange and I hope some can explain it. I set up a simple bash for loop that iterates a few numbers and copies files that has each number two times in the file name. This fails when not using `${var_name}` but succeeds when doing so. Here is a short example explaining what I mean:

```
$ touch 123.foo.123bar
$ touch 456.foo.456bar
$ mkdir out
$ for i in {123,456}; do cp $i.foo.$ibar out; done
cp: cannot stat `123.foo.': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `456.foo.': No such file or directory
$ for i in {123,456}; do cp ${i}.foo.${i}bar out; done
$ ls out
123.foo.123bar  456.foo.456bar
```

What is the reason that the first foor lopp fails while the second does not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write `$ibar`, bash understands that as `${ibar}`. Indeed, where should it end the variable name? (A dot is not allowed in a variable name, so `$i.` doesn't cause a problem.)

Another way to prevent the problem is to use backslashes:

```
cp $i.foo.$i\bar out
```

Comment: But why does it work fine at the first use `$i` and not at the second? Does the first `.` make any difference? In my experience it is not required to use `{}` when iterating in a for loop like this (when using the variable once).

Comment: @Krøllebølle: `.` cannot be a part of a variable name. "b" can.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. `for i in {123,456}; do cp $ifoo.$ibar out; done` fails in the same manner. I guess I have been lucky so far. Thanks!

Comment: Quoting anything that is not a variable also works. `$i.foo.$i"bar"`

Comment: @Jidder: Or quoting the variable `$i.foo."$i"bar` :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your first example references the variable `$ibar`, which is not defined.
The second one explicitly uses `$i`, which is what you want.

The variable name is expanded by bash until the first word separator, therefore `$i.foo` will be parsed as `${i}.foo`, since `.` terminates the word.

However, `$ibar` only ends at the whitespace and bash will therefore look for `${ibar}` in the scope.

Answer (score 1):

It is always a good practice to quote your arguments with variables on it around doublequotes (`""`) in a normal command to prevent unexpected word splitting and pathname expansion:

```
cp "$i.foo.$ibar" out
```

And if you find variables getting themselves adjacent to valid variable characters, the preferred solution would always be to use the `${}` format to keep it isolated. Quoting (like `cp "$i.foo.$i\bar" out`) may give confusion depending on implementation:

```
cp "${i}.foo.${i}bar" out
```

Using `${}` most of the time is not bad as well.

Comment: Which one do you refer to exactly? If you mean the first surely it won't, yet.

Comment: `cp "$i.foo.$ibar" out`

Comment: Of course. I haven't mentioned anything about adjacent variable characters there yet. Refer to the second one which is the true answer.

Comment: Ahh, okay , it was just a bit misleading.